# Doctrine update event on loaded Entity instance

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have problem with event in Doctrine , i need event on persist object that is already loaded

```
$obj = $em->getRepository(EntityName::class)->findById($someId);
$obj2 = clone $obj;
$obj2->property = 'some value';
$obj->property = 'some diff value';
$em->persist($obj2);
$em->persist($obj);
```

I register event in `EntityName` class on event `@PrePersist` and that works perfect for `$obj2` but event is not fired for `$obj`, is there way to delete `$obj` from `$em->UnitOfWorks` and fire event for `$obj`.

The trick is that i must fire event before `$em->flush()`

Comment: Perhaps onFlush? http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#onflush

Answer (score 4):

**[@PrePersist](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#prepersist)** only triggers when you are inserting a new entity.  If you've already found an existing entity like you have above, then you will need to use the **[@PreUpdate](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#preupdate)** event.

The [Doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html) contains information for all these events.

Of course, without knowing what you are attempting to do, and seeing your `@PrePersist` code, it's impossible to help you further.  You might be able to use `onFlush` like Cerad suggested.  You may need both `prePersist` and `preUpdate`.

Either way, merely calling `$em->persist()` does *not* guarantee that the `prePersist` event is going to be triggered.